# Step 7: XS_SECURITY LIB not available to P-users

Tags: s4sdk

in this blog https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/18/step-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-secure-your-application-on-sap-cloud-platform-cloudfoundry/ there is a link to download the XS security library. Unfortunately, it seems that P-users cannot access the SAP ONE Support Launchpad. Is there another repository where P-users can download this package from?[Image of the received message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQwVg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to download these libraries with a public (p) user at the moment. You need to get a support (s) user. The process to do this is:

- Go to https://launchpad.support.sap.com/
- Click on "User Management" tile
- Click "Request User" on the lower right
- Enter the user details
- Click "Submit"

Please note this might take up to 24 hours.

This process is also described in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wICiRTP8u0.